# Is my translation of "Under the light of the shining star" correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, translation-check

I've translated the title "Under the light of the shining star" into Latin:

> <s>Sub Lux Astri Lucens</s>

> Sub Luce Astri Lucentis

Is this correct? I've not learned participle forms of verbs yet, so I wasn't sure if it was correct in this usage. I'm also open to other vocabulary choices — I went with what would likely be most recognizable to a non-Latin speaker.

Comment: You need to also decline the words according to their case.

Comment: Ah, I forgot sub takes the accusative or ablative, and _lucens_ needs to match its noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Original attempt: *sub lux astri lucens*

Your choice of vocabulary is good, and the word order is natural.
What you are missing is some inflection.
There is no freedom of choice when it comes to case, number, and gender here.

Rather than giving you the full answer, I will give you a list of specific questions, as I believe this to be most useful for learning.
Please leave a comment below if you are unsure of the answers.

1. What should the case of *lux* be?
   It comes with the preposition *sub*.
2. What should the case of *astri* be?
   It describes the owner of the light.
3. What should the case and gender of *lucens* be?
   It modifies the star.
   Participles behave just like adjectives when it comes to choosing the correct case, gender, and number.

#### Updated attempt: *sub luce astri lucentis*

This is perfect!
(See the comments below for the discussion leading to this.)

Comment: _Sub_ uses the accusative when the object is in motion, and ablative when not, correct? How does that work with light? In modern terms, light is in motion so I would use the accusative, but I'm not sure that the Romans would have thought this.

Comment: @Adam What do you want to mean with the phrase? Usually it means being under the light. Passing underneath the light would make sense if you wanted to crawl under a projector so as not to disturb the film others are watching, but I can't think of many other reasonable uses. It doesn't matter whether the light moves or not, it's all about the thing under it, whether named or not.

Comment: Ok, I'm thinking just more generally being under it, so movement isn't really important. I'm not sure how to decline _lucens_ to match _astri_ in the genitive.

Comment: @Adam I thought so too, so ablative is the way to go. Have you been given a declension table of the participle? Like all present participles, it behaves like a third declension adjective. I assume that when you are introduced these participles, you would be told how to decline it.

Comment: Ahh, so _lucentis_ then.

Comment: @Adam Exactly! Now your translation is perfect.

Comment: Yay! Handy link on [participle declensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_conjugation#Participles) for anyone reading this later.

Comment: @Adam I hope guiding you through rather than giving you the answer worked out well. I thought, apparently correctly, that you only needed to be poked into the right direction. // [The A&G grammar](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-adjectives-classification-and-paradigms) lists those under third declension adjective declensions.

Comment: I greatly appreciate this approach - much more helpful for me and for others. Thank you!